# Jmeter values mapping

Tags: jmeter, hashmap, assertion

How to achieve a kind of mapping between string and numeric values that can be used for comparison in assertion? Example:

```
MAP "DELIVERED"=0
    "PENDING"=1
    "WAITING"=2 


sampler1 - extracted numeric_value=0
sampler2 - assert string value="DELIVERED" is equal to its numeric value
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below test plan:-

[image]

I have used variable name from regular expression of 1st sampler in the switch controller like ${regVar}..Then used the second request 3 times i.e. 0,1,2 and used response assertion with the desired value like "DELIVERED"=0 for first sampler under switch i.e "0" then in second "PENDING"=1 i.e "1"..so on.

With this, based on the regEx value from 1st http sample, only one http request will be send for 2nd sampler and that request have it own assertion. I have tried with both positive and negative cases. Please change the assertion value based on your requirements.

Please check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) which allows you to use arbitrary [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code to define pass/fail criteria.

You can access the `numeric_value` using **vars** shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class like:

```
def numericValue = vars.get('numeric_value')
```

Example code:

```
def myMap = ['0':'DELIVERED', '1':'PENDING', '2':'WAITING']

def numericValue = vars.get('numeric_value')

log.info('Numeric value is: ' + numericValue)
log.info('Status is: ' + myMap.get(numericValue))
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dmitri, implemented solution based on your suggestion and it suites fine.